# The problem with (co) bordism definition

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

According to one definition at Wiki:

An (n + 1)-dimensional cobordism is a quintuple (W; M, N, i, j) consisting of an (n + 1)-dimensional compact differentiable manifold with boundary, W; closed n-manifolds M, N; and embeddings i : M ⊂ ∂W, j : N ⊂ ∂W with disjoint images.

Note that n-manifolds are supposed to be closed, i.e. compact, without a boundary.

In 1 dimensional case you have a circle and it all makes sense.

However, I often see 0-dimensional manifold (a point) turning via bordism into a 1-dimensional manifold which is isomorphic to a closed interval in R. This 1-dimensional manifold *has a border*.

Then they construct 2-dimensional bordisms starting from it so what now happened to the definition that M and N are compact and have no border?

Edit based on comments:
Is there an expanded cobordism definition where M and N are allowed to have a boundary or a definition that includes corners?

Comment: It seems to me that what you are describing in the final paragraph are sometimes called *cobordisms with corners*.

Comment: I am referring to text:
http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2013-50-01/S0273-0979-2012-01393-9/S0273-0979-2012-01393-9.pdf
on cobordism hypothesis.

There, in figure 17 the definition given paragraphs above is suddenly blatantly ignored.

Comment: In this context, the author is most definitely talking about manifolds with corners, which require a bit of extra care than the ones without corners. You can not rely on the definition given on wikipedia for this case.

Comment: But here is a definition that author himself starts with:
Definition 2.4. Let Y0, Y1 be smooth compact (n − 1)-dimensional manifolds
without boundary. A bordism from Y0 to Y1 is a compact n-dimensional manifold
X with boundary, a decomposition ∂X = ∂X0  ∂X1, and diffeomorphisms
Yi → ∂Xi, i = 1, 2.

Comment: The author is not claiming that Figure 17 is an example of a cobordism according to the original definition.  Rather, it is an example of a more general notion that is what Section 5 is all about.

Comment: Fair enough but then: what is the most general definition of cobordism? Are incoming manifolds with or without boundary? That's what the question is really about.

Comment: If M and N can have a boundary then ∂W is not just a disjoint image of M and N, right? The definition above falls apart. I find it concerning that no more detailed definition is given.

Comment: @Tony If memory serves, there is a categorical definition of cobordism in Robert Stong's book (assuming you know a little category theory). This would probably be the most general definition you could hope for.

Comment: @Ben It's 1-categorical and not helpful for talking about the n-cobordism categories arising in the cobordism hypothesis. But I don't know a good reference for a careful definition of this cobordism category.